# Unable to get Webpack 4 to split/chunk Sass files

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-4

I have an ASP.Net MVC application where I am trying to have a stylesheet and javascript file per page.  As would be expected different pages are going to share a lot of code, particularly styles.  We used Sass for the styling and I am trying to get Webpack to code dedupe/split on the shared code.  I am using the mini-css-extract-plugin as well which I think might be part of my problem, but I digress. My path structure is as such:

/assets
-/js
-/styles
--/bootstrap
--/mixins
--/pages
---/page1
----page1.scss
---/page2
----page2.scss
--/utilities
--_general.scss
--_mixins.scss
--_utilities.scss
--app.scss

---

My app.css file looks like:

```
@import "./utilities/colors";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import './bootstrap/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import './bootstrap/selector-overrides';
@import './general';
@import "./mixins";
@import './utilities';
```

So at the top of page1.scss and page2.scss I have to import this app.scss file.  This results in essentially everything within app.scss being prepended to each file causing them to be 900k in size.

I've tried setting this app.scss file as a separate entry point and removing the import but then the pages can't build because they don't have build time access to these values.

I've tried multiple different configurations of the splitChunks configuration without any luck.

This is my current webpack.config.ts file:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import CleanWebpackPlugin from 'clean-webpack-plugin';
import * as ExtractCssChunks from 'extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
      app: ['./assets/js/index.js'],
      page1: ['./assets/js/pages/page1.ts'],
      page2: ['./assets/js/pages/page2.ts']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                ExtractCssChunks.loader,
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 2
                    }
                },
                'postcss-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        data: '$cloudinary_url: "";'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
output: {
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    library: 'LocalLib',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'app')
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
    }
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['**/*', path.join(process.cwd(), 'wwwroot/css/**/*')]
    }),
    new ExtractCssChunks({
        filename: "../css/[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "../css/[name].css"
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({}),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$': "jquery",
        'jQuery': "jquery",
        'window.jQuery': "jquery"
    })
],
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    alias: {
        jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
    }
}

};

export default config;
```

Ultimately, my question is this, how do I go about breaking out shared styles into a separate file that I can load and cache seperately from the individual page files.  Is there something I can do in Webpack to achieve this or do I need to rearrange my Sass files in a certain way?

Thank you in advance for any help.